# Русский перевод для "Ventricular run"

Tags: терминология

Этот вопрос больше к кардиологам, чем к лингвистам. Я очень прошу воздержаться от предположений и флуда.

Я программист и имею отношение к разработке кардиологического софта. Недавно заметил странный перевод английского текста на русский язык:

- "Supraventricular run" ► "Наджелудочковая пробежка"
- "Ventricular run (4 beats)" ► "Желудочковая пробежка"

К сожалению, я не могу судить, насколько хорош этот перевод. Мне он кажется странным. "Ventricular run" это 4 или более желудочковых импульсов подряд.

- Есть ли в русской кардиологической практике такое понятие, как "runs"?
- Это устоявшийся термин, или используется лишь в американской кардиологической практике?
- Это действительно называется "пробежка"?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=желудочковая%20пробежка

Comment: Прошу прощения, но это лингвистический сайт. Поэтому я бы не особо рассчитывал на ответы кардиологов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не кардиолог, но есть хороший сайт с тематическими словарями Мультитран, и там есть похожее выражение именно в медицинском словаре:

[run of ventricular tachycardia](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=run%20of%20ventricular%20tachycardia) — пробежка желудочковой тахикардии

Согласен, выражение странное.

Comment: Спасибо. Скорее всего это просто калька с английского за неимением лучшего. Со временем устаканится в головах. Уж лучше бы было слово "очередь".